# Deserialization NullReferenceException Object Reference With Classes Within Classes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, deserialization

My TypeA class:

```
   [Serializable]
   public class TypeA
   {
     public string m_Title { get; set; }

     [XmlIgnore]
     public TypeB m_Target {get; set;}

     public Int32 m_TypeBTargetID
     {
         get { return m_Target.m_ID; }
         set
         {  //the ID is passed to a function that returns
            //a specific TypeB that is in a list in the main thread
             m_Target = FindTypeB(value);
             m_TypeBTargetID= value;
         }
     }
```

My Main:

```
   public ObservableCollection<TypeA> A_Collection { get; set; }
    public void DeSerializeTypeACollection()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<TypeA>));
            System.IO.TextReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(
                @"c:\temp\myXML.xml");
            var d = reader.Deserialize(file);
            A_Collection = (ObservableCollection<TypeA>)d;
            file.Close();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

The result of serializing with one element in the collection and thus want I want to serialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfTypeA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <TypeA>
   <m_Title>test2</m_Title>
   <m_TypeBTargetID>32770</m_TypeBTargetID>
  </TypeA>
</ArrayOfTypeA>
```

The error I'm getting occurs at var d = reader.Deserialize(file);
The exception says There is an error in XML document(3,2) which is

```
 <TypeA>
```

Its always the start of the first element even with 20+ elements.

The inner exception says NullReferenceException Object Reference is not set to an instance of an object.

The TypeA is not getting correctly instantiated clearly. I have 2 theories as to why.

I have other variables in TypeA that are private as well, but everything gets instantiated in the constructor. I read somewhere that deserializing does not call the constructor so anything that needs to be initialized needs to be initialized elsewhere. Where though I'm not certain.

Or:

As for TypeB, TypeB cannot be initialized from within TypeA. It NEEDS that FindTypeB(id) function to be called, TypeB is made up elsewhere in the program at a very specific moment (which happens before I deserialize mind you so I do not believe that is the issue). I figured that by putting that under the set of m_TypeBTargetID it would solve that because that gets deserialized. Perhaps thats my issue rather than the private variables?

EDIT:

Stack Trace-

```
+       $exception  {System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (3, 4). ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Application.TypeA.Shutdown() in TypeA.cs:line 150
   at Application.TypeA.set_m_Enabled(Boolean value) in TypeA.cs:line 53
   at Application.TypeA..ctor() in TypeA.cs:line 68
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderObservableCollection1.Read3_TypeA(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderObservableCollection1.Read4_ArrayOfTypeA()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
   at Application.MainWindow.DeSerializeAlerts() in MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 393}    System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

Comment: Could you please share the stack trace? Specifically of the InnerException. If there is an "inner exception" it means that something happened elsewhere when the serializer was at the end of the first "TypeA" element and it just got passed on.

Comment: Can you show all your `TypeA` class, especially `m_Enabled` property?

Comment: That was it. Thank you, I realized I made a specific set property that would call Shutdown() that was only meant for when m_Enabled would be false. In this case, m_Enabled is default to false because thats what it defaults to. In my no variable constructor, I initialize it to true so now it wont Shutdown() when the deserializers sets it. I want to give you credit so just update your answer JleruOHeP if you would please. Idk maybe something like "take at look at your Shutdown() from set m_Enabled" :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setter for `m_TypeBTargetID` is quite strage. Seems like you forgot your private variable... Try  this:

```
[Serializable]
public class TypeA
{
  public string m_Title { get; set; }

  private TypeB _targetB
  [XmlIgnore]
  public TypeB m_Target 
  {
     get //Do you need that setter?
     {
        if (_targetB == null)
            _targetB = FindTypeB(m_TypeBTargetID);

        return _targetB;
     }
  }

  public Int32 m_TypeBTargetID {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. Your setup seems cleaner but it still throws with the same exceptions. I used the setter under TypeBTargetID thinking that when it deserializes, it will try to set the ID and then I would want it to pop the FindTypeB.

Comment: JleruOHeP pointed out that I have another variable m_Enabled that had its own set functions like Shutdown() that would only be called when false and never accounted for the deserializer setting it to default false.